# Run CLI commands using PHP script

Tags: php, ubuntu, terminal, avcodec

I want to convert a **flv** file to **mpg** using **avconv** it is run successively using terminal. My problem is run command using php script. I write a code but i did not got result. My code as follows

```
<?php
$cmd="avconv -i http://localhost/test3/a.flv http://localhost/test3/intermediate1.mpg";
$results = shell_exec($cmd.'2>&1');
?>
```

I tried also following code but no luck

```
<?php
$cmd="avconv -i /home/elby/workspace/test3/a.flv /home/elby/workspace/test3/intermediate1.mpg";
$results = shell_exec($cmd.'2>&1');
echo $results;
?>
```

Comment: Any more info? How does the code fail? Any error messages?

Comment: Have you checked to see if shell_exec works at all for you?, try something like `echo shell_exec('echo foo');` Depending on configuration, shell functions can be disabled.

Comment: There is a blank missing before `2>&1`, resulting in a filename `intermediate1.mpg2`in the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the first execute example is non-sense, according to [manual of `avconv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/avconv.1.html) it takes 2 parameters:

```
avconv [global options] [[infile options][-i infile]]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

And you cannot just tell program to save file to `http` protocol like that.

The second invocation... There are several possible issues with that:

- Are you running script from web or from CLI? Webserver may (and probably will) use different user which won't have an access to folders
- PHP scripts have [timeout (default 30 seconds)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) and video converting takes a lot more
- PHP may have [`shell_exec` disabled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)
- PHP may have [`safe_mode`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) turned on
- PHP may have a problem with `PATH` environment variable, try using absolute path
- With disabled [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) you may already have error logged but not displayed

Answer (score 0):

```
$cmd="avconv -i /home/elby/workspace/test3/a.flv /home/elby/workspace/test3/intermediate1.mpg";
$results = shell_exec($cmd.' 2>&1');
echo $results;
```

Use absolute path to avconv.